# hide tag with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Need some help with knockout binding. I have the following tag]

```
 <a class="link" data-bind="href: Url">My Url</a>
```

What I want to do is, if the "Url" is null or empty, hide the tag from view of the user.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
<a class="link" data-bind="attr: { href: url}, visible: url().length > 0">
    My Url
</a>
```

or if you don't want it to appear in the markup at all:

```
<!-- ko if: url().length > 0 -->
    <a class="link" data-bind="attr: { href: url}">
        My Url
    </a>
<!-- /ko -->
```